# XML element not displaying for empty values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am using an xml file to import into the database using the below code

**CS:**

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(pathPMO + "Data.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/DocumentElement/Profile");
bool insertProfile = false;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
   {
     strYear = node.SelectSingleNode("Profile_x0020_Year").InnerText;
     strID = node.SelectSingleNode("Profile_x0020_ID").InnerText;
     strLead = node.SelectSingleNode("Profile_x0020_Leader").InnerText;
     insertProfile = ImportProfile(strYear, strID, strLead);
    }
```

For instance the profile leader values are empty for certain rows and when I try to insert them I get an error `object not set to an instance of an object` because of that particular  element missing in few rows.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ensure that each XmlNode object is not null. You can use a simple method like that:

```
 private string GetXmlNodeString(string nodeName, XmlNode node)
 {
  if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nodeName))
     return String.Empty;

  var singleNode = node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName);

  if(singleNode ==null)
     return String.Empty;

  return singleNode.InnerText;
}
```

then change your code like that:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
 strYear = GetXmlNodeString("Profile_x0020_Year",node);
 strID =  GetXmlNodeString("Profile_x0020_ID",node);
 strLead = GetXmlNodeString("Profile_x0020_Leader",node);
 insertProfile = ImportProfile(strYear, strID, strLead);
}
```

Comment: is there anyway I can check in one liner?

Comment: what do you mean by one liner?

Comment: Can you please take a look at my post which looks similar to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749712/reading-xml-data-with-missing-attribute-values/33749793?noredirect=1#comment55267835_33749793