# Reading XML data with missing attribute values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am using an xml file to import data into the database using the below code. For that I am reading xml file an putting that into an array object. For attributes which are null the rows are missed out and unable to set empty string for those nodes.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(path + "Data.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/DocumentElement/Profile");

//read XML data and ID is one of the column
object[] ID = XDocument.Load(path + "Data.xml").Descendants("ID").Select(element => Element.Value).ToArray();
```

Now the ID element has null values and when I read them the rows with null values are omitted. How can I set empty string values for those null nodes?

Comment: I would suggest you to use xml serializer and deserializer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (See null coalesce operator ?? )

```
object[] ID = XDocument.Load(path + "Data.xml").Descendants("ID").Select(element => Element.Value ?? "").ToArray();
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it didn't add empty string to the missing attributes. We have to set empty string when we read the XML file.

Comment: In the question you asked about handling null values of ID attribute but not missing ID attribute. So what do you actually want to handle, missing value of ID attribute or the missing ID attribute itself?

Comment: Missing the ID attribute itself means the tag <ID> </ID> is not present in XML file.

Comment: I actually want to handle the missing attribute.

Comment: You will need a valid xsd to do this kind of validations. That means, if the xsd says, minoccurs for ID is 1, then it has to be there in the xml to consider it as a vaild xml. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331.aspx) for more information.